# How to intercept sms sent by user from android phone?

Tags: android, sms

I want to read sms sent by user in my application before it sent. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Any application can use `SmsManager` to send an SMS, and such messages cannot be intercepted, except perhaps by custom firmware.

Comment: for this type of questions ,generally people would say ,they are using an exploit and it would be soon fixed ! but how would these people are exploiting them ? is there any example to do so ? or are they listening to internal calls something like that ! can you enlighten me

Answer (score 0):

You cant block an outgoing sms.You can find out about it **only** after it has been sent. And you can do it by registering a content observer for sms, when the sms comes to sent box.

Answer (score 0):

You may intercept incoming messages if you want.

Here is an example of a SMS interceptor that "cancels" the SMS if it contains some custom defined data:

For your application to receive the message before it shows up in the phone you will have to define a receiver in the manifest with a high priority. Example:

```
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter android:priority="9999"> 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Then, create the receiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private static final String CRITICAL_MESSAGE = "critical";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null){
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);  
            if (msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString().equals(CRITICAL_MESSAGE)){
                str = "Critical msg from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " !";
                Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                abortBroadcast();
            }    
        }
    }
}

}
```

The above receiver cancels the SMS (aborts broadcast) if *critical* string is received.

Comment: `SEND_SMS` is a permission, not a broadcast `Intent` action. There is no use of `SEND_SMS` as a broadcast `Intent` action anywhere in the Android open source project.

Comment: You're right, my bad. I got carried away. I thought that by having a way to intercept incoming messages it's straightforward to intercept outgoing ones too.

Comment: op is asking the way to intercept before it's sent ,not "intercepting when msg arrives "